# Can I render a MOV with Jpeg2000 Codec with Blender?

Tags: rendering

Apparently, Blender has support for this codec. But I can not get my way across it. On a Mac, there are no options to select JPEG 2000, neither for images nor movie. On Windows, I did render image sequence with JPEG 2000 with Blender 2.67, But quicktime container did not have the codec. I want to render mov files with Alpha channel - thus JPEG 2000 (Animation and PNG were giving very large file sizes, and these files are to be made available for download.

Any pointers would be very helpful - horribly stuck.

Answer (score 2):

On OS-X you can render to PNG then open the files in preview and select export files to jpeg2000.

If it should be unclear, you can export multiple files at once by having them selected in the preview sidebar (<kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>).

I just hope it does take the alpha channel into account, haven't tested that yet.